# PHP `virtual()` with Apache MultiViews not working after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: configuration, apache2, php

I use PHP's `virtual()` directive quite a lot on one of my sites, including central elements. This worked fine for the last ~10 years -- but after upgrading to 12.04 it somehow got broken.

#### Example setup (simplified)

To make it easier to understand, I simplify some things (contents). So say I need a HTML fragment like `<P>For further instructions, please look <A HREF='foobar'>here</P>` in multiple pages. 10 years ago, I used SSI for that, so it is put into a file in a central place -- so if e.g. the targeted URL changes, I only need to update it in one place. To serve multiple languages, I have Apache's `MultiViews` enabled -- and at `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/central/` there are the files:

- `foobar.html` (English variant, and the default)
- `foobar.html.de` (German variant).

Now in the PHP code, I simply placed:

`<? virtual("/central/foobar"); ?>`

and let Apache take care to deliver the correct language variant.

#### The problem

As said, this worked fine for about 10 years: German visitors got the German variant, all others the English (depending on their preferred language). But after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, it no longer worked: Either nothing was delivered from the `virtual()` command, or (in connection with framesets) it even ended up in binary gibberish.

Trying to figure out what happens, I played with a lot of things. I first thought `MultiViews` was (somehow) not available anymore -- but calling `http://<server>/central/foobar` showed the right variant, depending on the configured language preferences. This also proved there was nothing wrong with file permissions. The `error.log` gave no clues either (no error message thrown).

Finally, just as a "last ressort", I changed the PHP command to `<? virtual("central/foobar.html"); ?>` -- and that very same file was in fact included. But the language dependend stuff obviously did no longer work.

Of course I tried to find some change (most likely in PHP's `virtual()` command), using Google a lot, and also searching the questions here -- unfortunately to no avail.

#### Finally: The question

Putting "design questions" aside (surely today I would design things differently -- but at least currently I miss the time to change that for a quite huge amount of pages): **What can be done to make it work again?** I surely missed something -- but I cannot figure out what...

#### Addition (EDIT)

My remaining problem now is that as soon as the document needs to be negotiated (e.g. has different language variants), `virtual()` always adds the content at the very beginning of the generated document (i.e. in front of the `<HTML>` tag) -- regardless where it was placed. It however gets placed correctly when no negotiation is involved.

Any idea what's going on there, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As the "binary gibberish" mentioned above made me curious, I investigated a bit further and copy-pasted it into a file named `foo.gz`, and ran `gzip -d foo.gz`. As already suspected, this yielded no error message (though the output still was gibberish -- just different gibberish). Comparing the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` on my new machine with a similar setup on an older machine turned up **`mod_deflate`** being enabled on the new machine. So I removed that from the enabled mods (by simply deleting the symbolic links `deflate.conf` and `deflate.load`), reloaded Apache... problem solved. At least it looks like...

**Edit:**

Only the "gibberish part" is solved by disabling `mod_deflate`. Remaining issue: As soon as the link passed to `virtual()` triggers `mod_negotiation` (i.e. the *MultiViews* part), the included text is moved to the very top of the output (i.e. *in front of* the `<HTML>` tag), which breaks most pages. If the targeted link does not need to be negotiated, the included text is placed correctly. Very confusing.